# Error installing "ros-indigo-ros-controllers"

Tags: ros, p3at

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use ros-gazebo-p3at.
I have installed ubuntu 14.04/ Ros-indigo / and gazebo as given [here](http://people.oregonstate.edu/%7Echungje/Code/Pioneer3dx%20simulation/ros-indigo-gazebo2-pioneer.pdf) .

But while installing ros-controller;

```
 sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-ros-controllers
```

i am getting an error;

```
Err http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/ trusty/main ros-indigo-force-torque-sensor-controller i386 0.9.3-0trusty-20160627-193242-0700
  403  Forbidden
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-indigo-force-torque-sensor-controller/ros-indigo-force-torque-sensor-controller_0.9.3-0trusty-20160627-193242-0700_i386.deb  403  Forbidden

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

What to do.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246048/error-installing-%22ros-indigo-ros-controllers%22/) by [sumant](https://answers.ros.org/users/20291/sumant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2016-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this a duplicate of [Error while installing ros-indigo-ros-controllers](http://answers.ros.org/question/243040)?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1